# How to get entities with only 1 relation?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT p0_.id                AS id
FROM product p0_
         LEFT JOIN product_color_group p7_ ON p0_.id = p7_.product_id
         LEFT JOIN color_group c3_ ON c3_.id = p7_.color_group_id
WHERE c3_.id IN (17, 15)
GROUP BY p0_.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c3_.id) = 1
ORDER BY p0_.id ASC
LIMIT 18;
```

In the table product_color_group i have only product_id and color_group_id

I need to show products that have only one of the selected colors (or 17 or 15). But the request also returns goods that have, for example, colors 17 and 3. What is the problem?

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: You seem to have posted a Hibernate-generated MySQL query, which is hard to read.  Instead, can you post sample input and output data for this problem?

Comment: *"How to get entities with only 1 relation?"* Also That would require INNER JOIN instead right as you want existing relations only

Comment: Just remove the distinct constraint in the count, `DISTINCT c3_.id` means only one of each color group, but you only want one color group. You should also post your LINQ statement, the reason why the distinct is wrong should be more obvious there

Comment: What about a product which has both color groups(17 & 15) which are selected, would it be selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the selected Color Group: 17, 15.

Below query will list out products which have color group:

- Only 17
- Only 15
- Both 17 And 15 but not other color groups.

```
SELECT p.id
FROM product p
INNER JOIN product_color_group pcg ON p.id= pcg.product_id
INNER JOIN color_group cg ON cg.id = pcg.color_group_id
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING SUM(IF(pcg.color_group_id IN (15, 17), 0, 1)) = 0;
```

Note: If you want to exclude products which have color groups `both 17 and 15 only` use below query.

```
SELECT p.id
FROM product p
INNER JOIN product_color_group pcg ON p.id= pcg.product_id
INNER JOIN color_group cg ON cg.id = pcg.color_group_id
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING SUM(IF(pcg.color_group_id IN (15 ,17), 0, 1)) = 0 AND COUNT(0) = 1;
```